# How to remove driver from blacklist in ubuntu?

Tags: blacklist

I was following some answer to unblock hard-blocked wifi. I type the following command

`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hhp_wmi"`

and ended up removing wifi option completely.

Now I want to unblock that any help here how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file and remove the line that says `blacklist hhp_wmi`. You can do that with nano if need be

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf
```

or if it is the only line in the file (and that IS likely) you could also delete it with

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf
```

---

Not sure if needed but do a reboot after removing the file.

Comment: Yeah but still it's not showing wifi option any idea why ?

Comment: "unblock hard-blocked wifi" if you want that solved make another question. There are specific people on here that specialize in that question :D

Comment: And some of those people look forward to your new question!

Comment: THERE HE IS! The expert i mentioned ;) He made one but it got closed due to being 16.10 (I edited it out of this question thinking it would not matter :))